# Subjunctive vs. Indicative in Conditional Phrases

Tags: gramática, conjugación

I have recently been studying the subjunctive and conditional phrases in Spanish. I attempted to translate the following English sentence/though "If there is rain tonight and it's very stormy, we will watch 'Lost Highway.'

I translated the above as "Si esta noche haya mucho lluvia y este muy tormentosa, vamos a ver 'Lost Highway.'

My Spanish speaking friends are telling me this pairing of present subjunctive and the present indicative is right, but websites are telling me that for such a conditional situation (one in which the condition [rain] is not unlikely/improbable) the pairing should be present indicative/present indicative or present indicative/present future.

I hope someone can be of help in sorting this out. Thank you

Comment: You are translating literally. If there is rain tonight is not mucha lluvia. It's **si llueve**. Si llueve mucho hoy por la noche y hay mucha tormenta. stormy as tormentoso is not idiomatic in everyday Spanish.

Comment: The sentence in English sounds clumsy, IMHO it would be much more common to just say ‘if it rains tonight’ = si llueve, as @Lambie comments

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Gustavson.

> "Si esta noche <s>haya</s> mucho lluvia y este muy tormentosa, vamos a ver 'Lost Highway.'

"Esté muy tormentosa" is a somewhat literary you find in writing something like that and I wouldn't translate "there is" as "haya" here, as already mentioned above. If you mean "haya" you’ll need to recast the sentence.

- "Aunque hay**a** (subjunctive present) un temporal, igual(de igual forma) vamos a ver 'Lost Highway"(Even if there is...we will..)
- "Aunque lluev**a** (subjunctive present) o truene(subjunctive present), (igual) vamos a ver 'Lost Highway"
- "Aún cuando lluev**a** o truen**e** (singular 3rd person subjunctive present), (igual) vamos a ver 'Lost Highway"

But "even if" has a different meaning here. We will watch a movie, no matter what the circumstances.

> "If there is rain tonight and it's very stormy, we will watch 'Lost Highway.'

In a colloquial way I would say:

- "Si hay temporal, vamos a ver una película" (someone's talking about their plans)
- "Si hay temporal, **vemos [indicative present]** una película mejor" (the present has future value in this context, using the word "mejor" makes this sound more like a suggestion than a command, it's better if we stay here, if it rains, the best plan is/it's better if you dont go out)
- "Si lluev**e** (indicative present singular 3rd person), **veremos [indicative future]** una película" (thinking in advance what you are going to do)
- "Si lluev**e** y hay mucho viento mejor nos quedamos (indicative present) viendo una película, ¿Qué les parece?"(= If it rains, we'll just stay inside and watch... what do you think?) (It's just a suggestion)
- En el caso de que lluev**a** (subjunctive), lo que **podríamos[indicative conditional]** hacer es ver una película (it is a possible scenario)

If the weather forecast says it will be cloudy with a slight chance of rain, then we would say:

- Si se **diera** el caso de que llueva/Si **lloviera**|**lloviese**/Si **llegara**|**llegase** **a llover**, entonces mejor vemos/**veríamos [indicative conditional]**/veremos una película/lo que seguramente **haríamos [indicative conditional]**/haremos **sería [Indicative conditional]**/es ver una película (that is what we would do in that situation if this happens)

IF CLAUSES THAT REQUIRE SUBJUNCTIVE FORM -> Hypothetical situations in the future or the present that are contrary to fact or **very unlikely**: Si+imperfect subjunctive+the conditional, e.g: Si llueve/**lloviera [subjunctive imperfect]**, no saldré/**saldría [Indicative conditional]** (if it were to rain, I wouldn't go out)

Si (If) is very rarely followed by the present subjunctive but the rule can be broken -> Especially with negative 'si' clauses (such as - no se si...) the present subjunctive is something to express more doubt, ''si" then takes on the meaning of 'whether' more than 'if'. E.g. No se si **estemos (subjunctive present plural 1st person)** en casa (I don't know whether we'll be at home)

Answer (score 3):

Unlike other conditional linkers that take the present subjunctive, "si" is always followed by the indicative if the present tense is used:

1. Siempre que (*Provided that*) esta noche haya mucha lluvia y esté muy tormentoso, vamos a ver 'Lost Highway'.
2. Suponiendo que (*Assuming that*) esta noche haya mucha lluvia y esté muy tormentoso, vamos a ver 'Lost Highway'.
3. Con la condición de que (*On condition that / As long as*) esta noche haya mucha lluvia y esté muy tormentoso, vamos a ver 'Lost Highway'.

(In sentences 1 to 3, we would tend to place the condition at the end of the sentence.)

4. A menos que (*Unless*) esta noche haya mucha lluvia y esté muy tormentoso, vamos a ver 'Lost Highway'. (In this case, the idea is that, if it is rainy and stormy, they will do something else.)

BUT

5. **Si** (*If*) esta noche **hay** mucha lluvia y **está** muy tormentoso, vamos a ver 'Lost Highway'.

Note 1: We don't speak about conditional phrases but conditional clauses.

Note 2: Please note that "lluvia" is feminine, so you say "mucha lluvia", and although "noche" is feminine, we can use masculine "tormentoso" to refer to the weather.

Comment: The OP's translation from English is faulty. Therefore, the Spanish comes out badly.

Comment: I agree. I just tried to focus on the question of the mood, which was OP's main interest.